# Angular service into directive through ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make a custom directive to create a menu where the href value changes depending on the family.id value which I got via service.

I'm trying to use that family.id value of each element in ng-repeat to query a new value through a service and change the href depending on that value

**product.html**

```
<ul class="list" custom-href categories="getfamilies"></ul>
```

**href.js**

```
 (function(){
    var app = angular.module('hrefDirective',['productsService']);

    app.directive('customHref',['productsService', function(productsService) {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            transclude: false,
            scope: {
                categories: '='
            },
            template: '<li ng-repeat="family in categories"><p><a ng-bind="family.name" ng-href="{{newHref}}"></a></p></li>',           
            link : function($scope,$element, $attrs){
                productsService.finalFamilies(family.id).then(function(data){
                    if(data == 0){
                        $scope.newHref = '#/product/';
                    }else{
                        $scope.newHref = '#/product/{{family.id}}';
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }]);

})();
```

**products.js**

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('productosController',['productsService']);

    app.controller('ProductsFamiliesController', function($scope, productosService){    

        productsService.getFamilies().then(function(data){
            $scope.getfamilies = data.data;
        });

    });

})();
```

**services.js**

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('productsService',[]);

    app.factory('productsService', ['$http','$location', function($http, $location){

        var webServiceUrl = 'my url'
        var products = [];

        products.getFamilies = function(){
            return $http.get(webServiceUrl+'getFamilies');
        };
        products.finalFamilies = function(idFamily){
            return $http.get(webServiceUrl+'getFinalFamiles?id'+ idFamily);
        };

        return products;

    }]);

})();
```

Of course is not working...any clues...?

[plnkr.co/edit/3N19E0KyeWW7wvsLOlkk?p=info](http://plnkr.co/edit/3N19E0KyeWW7wvsLOlkk?p=info)

Comment: In the link function (in the directive) you are creating a private variable `var newHref` you have `$scope` available in a link, try using `$scope.newHref` instead.

Comment: I've just changed var `newHref` for `$scope.newHref` but still not working throw an error Cannot read property 'finalFamilies' of undefined

Comment: I've changed the code to inject the service into the directive a now  I'm getting `ReferenceError: familia is not defined`, from the link productService.finalFamilies function

Comment: Any chance of a Fiddle or Plunker version?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/3N19E0KyeWW7wvsLOlkk?p=info, @camden_kid

Comment: Check this updated plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/qkTlMuUtqcDaHWSUluwG